# login access on email varification in silverlight 4

Tags: email, silverlight-4.0, user-registration

We have applicaiton in silverlight 4. In our application,we have funcationlity to send mail on registration of any user on our site. after that user need to go their email and click on the link then only they can access to login in the site next time.

In this, we have done the code for sent email on registration but dont know how to do when user clicks on link and allow to login next time.
so can any one help me out how to do this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just store a flag associated with the user account that says whether the account has been confirmed or not. Then check that flag when the user tries to log in, and disallow logins to unconfirmed accounts.

Somehow, I get the feeling that there is actually more to your question than this, but if so, it'd help if you clarify.